# How to import a Wagtail page on all the other wagtail pages

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I want to add some content on one of my Wagtail pages and I am trying to import that Wagtail page on all my other wagtail pages. The reason I am trying to do this is that if in the future I make a change on the content it should consistently reflect on all the other Wagtail pages.
Is there a way that I can import a Wagtail page on all my other Wagtail pages, if so please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

I have a website which has the following Configurations:
1) Django-2.0.8
2) Wagtail-2.2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/) is a good way to achieve this, as it provides a place to run custom Python code (for retrieving the necessary data) before outputting the results to the template, either directly as a string or by rendering a template. For example, if you had a `footer_text` field on a `HomePage` model, and wanted to display the footer text of the `HomePage` with slug 'home' on every page, you could define a custom tag as follows:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/includes/footer.html')
def footer():
    homepage = HomePage.objects.get(slug='home')
    return {'footer_text': homepage.footer_text}
```

You could also look at Wagtail's [site settings](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html) module as a way to define global content to be re-used across a site (although it's missing a few features that you'd get from defining it on a page model, such as moderation workflow and revision history).